# Use login and password stored in my setting in the ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am new to cocoa.

I want to authenticate with my webservice but I want to use the login and password that I saved in my setting in the Ipad.

**Function:**

```
  NSMutableArray *test12 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        test12 =  [SYNchronisationClass synchroniseGlobalLists:clientId:IDShopGlobal:userLogin:userPassword];
  NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement setting bundle in your app and add username, password info in setting plist.

this link, helps you.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html